# Filter specific data from a http response

Tags: r, http

I made a http request to get specific value (like age which is equal to 30 in this example) from a webpage exploiting REST API, but when I'm trying to parse content I get some other values too (like surename and firstname).

I'm using R httr package:

```
age <- httr::content(httr::GET(http://192.168.10.xx/info))
```

Content of the response:

```
surename=smith,firstname=adam,age=30
```

In R I can use `substring(age, nchar(age)-1)` to get age from this vector, but my problem is that I need to shift to another program where a more simplified way is required as only three parameters can be defined (url, header, body). Thus I'm trying to apply filter right in the url to avoid R specific transformations, but it does not work:

```
age <- httr::content(httr::GET(http://192.168.10.xx/info?age))
PARAM NG,msg=404 Not Found"
```

Comment: Without knowing how your API endpoint/ GET request is structured, it‘s impossible to help, i.e. does your API endpoint allow for filtering on age?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no detailed documentation for this API. So without it, there is no chance to filter on age?

Comment: I didn't say that. There might be a chance to filter on age, but without knowing how the APi is structured, it's impossible to say if and if yes, how your request has to be coded, e.g. I have a REST API where I can specify certain variables to retrieve via the `?fields=age` parameter and filter on a certain age by e.g. `cond:age=30`. But that's likely not gonna work for you.

Comment: Having said that, usually there APIs have some sort of documentation. If you let us know which API, we could maybe check. Otherwise I'd say, reach out to the website admin, they should usually be able to help in setting up the request.